# Open TCP port on cable modem TG1672G

Tags: nmap, tcp

TG1672G cable modem in bridge mode, the modem's built in router still gets a IPv4/IPv6 public address (and devices connected to the modem can get public IPv4/IPv6 addresses too). This modem is Intel PUMA6+RT3593.

nmap shows `9081/tcp open     unknown.`

```
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

How can I find out what this port is used for? The modem in bridge mode shouldn't get a public IP address to begin with, not to mention an opened port.

```
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=6.40%E=4%D=11/18%OT=9081%CT=1%CU=33663%PV=N%DS=3%DC=I%G=Y%TM=564C
OS:6CB8%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=C4%GCD=1%ISR=CC%TI=Z%CI=Z%TS=7)SEQ(SP=
OS:C4%GCD=1%ISR=CC%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=7)OPS(O1=M5B4ST11NW0%O2=M5B4ST11NW0%O3
OS:=M5B4NNT11NW0%O4=M5B4ST11NW0%O5=M5B4ST11NW0%O6=M5B4ST11)WIN(W1=2D40%W2=2
OS:D40%W3=2D40%W4=2D40%W5=2D40%W6=2D40)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=2DA0%O=M5B4NNSNW
OS:0%CC=N%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF
OS:=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=
OS:%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=N)U1(R=Y%DF=N%
OS:T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=40%CD
OS:=S)


1 service unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprint at http://www.insecure.org/cgi-bin/servicefp-submit.cgi :
SF-Port9081-TCP:V=6.40%I=9%D=11/18%Time=564D259B%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu%r(G
SF:etRequest,5,"0\n0\n\n")%r(FourOhFourRequest,5,"0\n0\n\n")%r(OfficeScan,
SF:5,"0\n0\n\n")%r(apple-iphoto,6,"9003\n\n")%r(metasploit-msgrpc,5,"0\n0\
SF:n\n")%r(hazelcast-http,5,"0\n0\n\n");
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Can you put a packet sniffer in front of it?

Comment: The device in question is a DOCSIS modem. Do you have recommendations for tapping a cable modem's outside interface?

Comment: Wait - where are you running the nmap scan from? Inside your network or outside?

Comment: I got the same result from both inside and outside (Internet). That's what raised my security concern. I don't have the equipment to capture traffic between modem and CMTS.

Comment: you need to include that detail in your question

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf your best bet is to access the internal serial port which often gives you a root shell with default credentials, from there you can run `tcpdump` on the cable interface (but if you have a shell you can directly run `netstat` and look at which process is listening on the aforementioned port).

Answer (score 2):

Use Nmap's [service version detection](http://nmap.org/book/vscan.html). Using a recent version of Nmap (so that you have the most complete database of probes and response matches), run:

```
nmap -sV -p 9081 1.2.3.4
```

And the result should be shown. If the port responds to *any* of Nmap's probes, you will either get a positive match or the response will be shown in a blob at the end of the scan with a request for you to submit it to Nmap for further identification. You can often get some idea by looking at the blob what kind of service is running, even if Nmap doesn't really know.

Comment: If service is unknown, I doubt version detection is going to do much. "PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
9081/tcp open  unknown
1 service unrecognized despite returning data"

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf That "despite returning data" part means you should have been given a service fingerprint (block of lines all starting with "SF"). That contains the data the probes returned, and is critical for knowing what the service is. 
Also, what version of Nmap do you have? New service matches are added all the time.

Comment: Could also try `nmap -sV --version-all -p 9081 1.2.3.4`. Might have better luck there.